# magento 2.3.5p1 all configureable products showing out of stock

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.3.5p1 store has been running fine. No changes have been made. This morning ALL configurable products are showing out of stock. The strange part is ALL the configurable products that are part of a Bundle are working as expected.

I have reset (invalidated indexes), re-indexed all data and flushed caches still showing out of stock. I have verified that all settings in backend have not been changed.

Anyone else run into this? Any Suggestions will be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be checking the actaul store's stock status, and not the default.

There is a thread on magento's forums with a couple of possible solutions like:

1. Checking the stack status of the store(s)
2. making sure that the simple products related to the configurable product are not set to out of stock by default

Here is the [link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Can-Magento-do/Configurable-product-showing-out-of-stock-everything-is-right-in/td-p/4352)